# Big Word App, Using Canvas Javafx, Interesting Challenge

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, javafx

Interesting Challenge:
Trying to create an app that shows the form of a large word composed a bunch of repeating text entered by the user.

I have used `PixelReader` to get every point from an image of the letter `A`:

```
//create pixel readers and writer to write to canvas
    PixelReader pixreader = imga.getPixelReader();  
    PixelWriter pixwriter = gc.getPixelWriter();

    //point arrays
    ArrayList<Integer> xpoints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ypoints = new ArrayList<>();

    //Read shape of letter by the color of its pixels against a white background
    for(int readY=0;readY<imga.getHeight();readY++){
        for(int readX=0;readX<imga.getWidth();readX++){

            Color color = pixreader.getColor(readX, readY);
            if(!color.equals(Color.WHITE) ){
                //color = Color.TRANSPARENT; 
                xpoints.add(readX);
                ypoints.add(readY);
            }                     
        }
    }
```

I get the jumble of words from the user with :

```
public void writeOut(String bigWord, String littlewords){

    HBox word = new HBox();
    word.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

    String[] letters = bigWord.split("\\B");
    littleWordArray = littlewords.split(" ");
    inputText = littlewords;


private String getRandomSmallWord(){
    int size = littleWordArray.length;
    return littleWordArray[rand.nextInt(size)];
}
```

The problem is now I have all these points that form an `A` I want to uniformly write the text within that mold...

I have failed with a few attempts along the lines of:

```
for(int ix = 0;ix<xpoints.size();ix+=100){
    String nextWord = getRandomSmallWord();
    int nextwordlength = nextWord.length();
    int currentX = xpoints.get(ix);
    int currentY = ypoints.get(ix);
    gc.strokeText(nextWord,currentX,currentY);
    //gc.strokeText(nextWord,currentX+5,currentY+5);
    //gc.strokeText(getRandomSmallWord(),(currentX+nextwordlength),currentY,30.0);
    System.out.println("("+currentX+", "+currentY+")");

}
```

I am reaching out to the senior developers out there lend me your wisdom!

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.  Do you have an image containing an example of the results you desire?  Can you provide example values for `bigWord` and `littlewords`?

Comment: Yea I have stock black and white block images of all the letters, I haven't gotten past 'A' but pixreader draws all the coordinates of all points that form that image. bigWord and littlewords are just whatever the user enters, that part is irrelevent.

Comment: The sooner you can update your question with example input and example output, the sooner I can understand your problem.  I understand you are saving the pixels of a letter A, but I don’t understand what you are trying to do with those pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this isn't really a StackOverflow style question and perhaps I shouldn't answer it here.  But anyway, here is a sample of one approach to create a word consisting of smaller words.  It doesn't use a Canvas, but instead just uses blended labels.   It is probably not useful to you, but might give you some ideas to think about.  At least, I hope it helps you to edit and clarify your question to help more fully explain what it is you are trying to accomplish and what is the precise issue that is preventing you from getting it done.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class WordViewer extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_ITERATIONS = 200;
    private static final String bigWords =
            "Lorem";
    private static final String littleWords =
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label smallLabel = new Label(
                IntStream.range(0, NUM_ITERATIONS)
                        .mapToObj(i -> littleWords)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
        );
        smallLabel.setStyle(
                "-fx-font-size: 9px; " +
                "-fx-background-color: black; " +
                "-fx-text-fill: white"
        );
        smallLabel.setWrapText(true);
        smallLabel.setPrefWidth(1350);

        Label largeLabel = new Label(bigWords);
        largeLabel.setStyle(
                "-fx-font-size: 400px; " +
                "-fx-background-color: black; " +
                "-fx-text-fill: white"
        );

        largeLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(smallLabel.widthProperty());
        largeLabel.prefHeightProperty().bind(smallLabel.heightProperty());
        largeLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        largeLabel.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(
                smallLabel,
                largeLabel
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's brilliant! I didn't know anything about blend mdoes!

Comment: Makes a somewhat difficult problem a very easy one ;-)